# Lightweight command-line image resizer?

Tags: imagemagick, thumbnails, utility, freeimage, graphicsmagick

I'm looking for an image resizer / thumbnailer that is lightweight and efficient.  Something that does a good job with all image types, but most importantly jpeg and png.

I've looked into ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick, but they are too heavy.  This is something I want to distribute with my app, so the smaller the better.  I don't need all the functionality of *Magick, just simple resizing.

I've found the FreeImage library which people seem to like as a light library.  Does anyone know if there's a simple command-line utility that wraps FreeImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/) toolkit, the toolkit is just a bunch of small single purpose command line programs that you wire together using pipes. You might be able to find what you need in there.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  We actually ended up going with a build of GraphcisMagick with only the necessary libs.  Not tiny, but small enough.

Answer (score 4):

Although ImageMagick is pretty big (36.2MB), you only need the `convert.exe` or `mogrify.exe` binary, depending on whether you want to create a new image (`convert`), or overwrite the existing one (`mogrify`).

[Download](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) the no-installer version of ImageMagick (currently ImageMagick-6.8.6-8-Q16-x86-windows.zip), then extract the binary you need.

I took `mogrify.exe` - a total of 5.66MB; not bad!

Answer (score 0):

On linux/OSX can use `sips`

```
sips -Z 640 *.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

i have bulk image contain in a directory name with test And i want to re-size all of them single command line

```
cd /test/
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec convert -quality 75 {} /var/www/html/converted/{} \;
```

/var/www/html/converted/  this used for where converted image will save .